# how to align columns vertically so that adjacent rows not align with each other

Tags: html, alignment

How can I align the td vertically so that it looks like below and the text box will be next to the "aaaa:" and aligned with it horizontally as well?

https://jsfiddle.net/rgw870ta/

```
enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to do it with tables? Can you use a div-based layout? Can you use bootstrap?

Comment: this is what I got with bootstrap grid: https://jsfiddle.net/smwgfdmn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code and its output, I'm a bit confused what you actually want but I guess one of following will help you!

```html
    

    <table style="width: 100%;display:table-cell;" border="0">
                <tr valign="top" >
                    <td style="width: 50px" align="right">And<br /> And</td>
                    <td style="display:block; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:70px"> 
                        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:
                        <br />
                         bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                        <br />
                         cccccccccccccccccccc
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="lname">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
<br>
<br>

        <div style="display:  flex;align-items:  center;
">
                <div style="width: 50px" align="right">And<br /> And</div>
                <div style="display:block; margin-left:20px;"> 
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:
                    <br />
                     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                    <br />
                     cccccccccccccccccccc
                </div>
                <div>
                                <input type="text" name="lname">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <table style="width: 70%" border="0">
                <tr valign="top" >
                    <td style="width:10px">And<br /> And</td>
                    <td style="width:20px;text-align:left; "> 
                        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:
                        <br />
                         bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                        <br />
                         cccccccccccccccccccc
                    </td>
                    <td  style="width:70px;text-align:left;">
                                    <input type="text" name="lname">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if that's what you're after... I think you missed the `div` with class `container` wrapping all the rows.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-md-12">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:</div>
  </div>


  <div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5 ">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:</div>
    <input style="margin-top:-5px" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">And</div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 text-right">And</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume this is what you need:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>A</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4  col-xs-4">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>A  </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ">
            <div class="col-xs-2">

            <input type="text">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

resize the uotput window check:
https://jsfiddle.net/3q3egbqs/